# how to put a foreach loop within an elseif clause

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, mediawiki

I would like to show ads NOT if title == MainPage or if category == Portal. 
I'm trying to create an if, elseif, else statment but I'm not sure where to put the foreach loop. 
This is my code:

```
<?php
     $id =  $wgTitle->getArticleID();
        $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
        $result = $dbr->query("SELECT page_id FROM wiki_page ORDER BY page_latest");
        while( $row = $dbr->fetchObject( $result ) ) {              
        foreach($row as $page_id){$m_array = array($page_id);}
        }
        $title = Title::newFromText( $wgRequest->getVal( 'title' ) );
        $categories = $title->getParentCategories();

    if(in_array($id, $m_array)){
        if($wgTitle == "Main Page"){} 
        foreach ($categories as $category => $article_title){
         elseif($category == 'Category:Portal'){ echo "no ads";}
        }       
        else{echo 'show ads';}
    } 
    ?>
```

I can't put the elseif in the foreach loop but how to I specify the $category clause? If I wrap the whole code in the foreach loop then the ads show multiple times as there are multiple categories for some pages.

(mediawiki site)
Thanks

Comment: This is php? PLease include a language tag

Answer (score 0):

You use a boolean to store the result of your test. Consider this:

```
$ok = $title != 'Main Page';
foreach($categories as $c => $at) $ok = $ok && $c != 'Category:Portal';
if($ok) echo "show ads";
else echo "no ads";
```